# PageSpeed Insights Detects Render Blocking JS and CSS in my Website. How do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, css, performance, web

How do I remove render blocking JavaScript and fix this problem?

I am not using any CMS. I am using only static HTML.

When submitting my page's URL to [Google PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/), I get the following warnings:

```
Remove render-blocking JavaScript:

http://www.mxxxxx.com/scripts/custom.js
http://www.mxxxxx.com/js/jqueryui.min.js
http://www.mxxxxx.com/scripts/jquery
http://www.mxxxxx.com/scripts/jqueryui

Optimize CSS Delivery of the following:

http://www.mxxxx.com/styles/style1.css
http://www.mxxxx.com/styles/framework.css
http://fonts.googleapis.com/…,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800
http://fonts.googleapis.com/…,400italic,600italic,700italic,900italic
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900
http://fonts.googleapis.com/…00,500italic,700,700italic,900italic,900
http://fonts.googleapis.com/…?family=Signika+Negative:300,400,600,700
http://www.mxxxx.com/styles/owl.theme.css[need fix[\]\[1\]][1]
```

Here is a screen shot of the actual error page:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9FJn.png

Comment: Clarified which tool the poster is using that she gets the error message from. Fixed capitalization.

Comment: how to fixed patrick? i am confuse

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article which shows you step by step to get the Pagespeed score of 100: https://www.storyblok.com/tp/how-to-get-pagespeed-100

Probably the most time intensive task is to identify the above the fold CSS and inline them in the head section. The below the fold CSS and the fonts you can include after the closing html tag or using a async method with https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS

The Javascript files you can easily put at the end of you html document. Before the closing body tag. But I would merge them to one to have less http requests.

Answer (score 0):

Add Expires headers

We define our Expires Headers in the .htaccess file. This is a hidden file often found in the root of your website (via FTP). It's always best practice before you edit the htaccess file to back it up!

More Details:- https://gtmetrix.com/add-expires-headers.html